# Creating a thread to access another class's prviate procedures and variables

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have been using c++ for long time and I am not good at Delphi (XE). But for reason, I have to port my c++ code to Delphi to implement the following task. I have a main TForm which I obtained the code from someone else. In the TForm, I have 2 private objects and procedures defined to finish some task. My task is to create a thread to call those classes and procedures for some calculation.

```
TASKForm = class(TForm)
  private
    MonitorA :TMonClassA;
    ConstB :TConstClassB;

    procedure calculateStmp;
end;
```

This task could be done easily in c++ if I extend TASKForm with multi-inheritance. But after some research, I found that Delphi doesn't support that. So I need to think of other way. I then saw an article about using the nested class.

```
TASKForm = class(TForm)
  protected
    TMyThread = class(TThread)
      public
        procedure Execute(); override; // inside this I need to call TASKForm.MonitorA.somemethod, TASKForm.ConstB.somemethod and TASKForm.calculateStmp
    end
  private
    MonitorA :TMonClassA;
    ConstB :TConstClassB;

    procedure calculateStmp;
end;
```

But I soon find that the procedure defined in the nested class cannot access the container's private members. I wonder if there is any other way I can create an thread to call one class's private functions and variables? Thanks.

---

code updated. I am trying two more schemes. The first one is to use interface like

```
TmyThread = interface(TThread)
end;

TASKForm = class(TForm, TmyThread)
private
  MonitorA :TMonClassA;
  ConstB :TConstClassB;

  procedure calculateStmp;
end;
```

But it does not work because TThread is not a type of interface. I am trying to use Application.ProcessMessages, like the following

```
procedure TASKForm.RunMyTask;
  while (not RunTerminated) do // RunTerminated will be set when an external event triggered
  begin
    MonitorA.Somemethod;
    calculateStmp;
    ConstB.Somemethod;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
end
```

I will say this method is "ok" but not perfect because the MonitorA.Somemethod and ConstB.Somemethod may take long or short time to run (the time is not constant) so sometimes when external event triggered to set RunTerminated True, it will not terminate the while loop immediately. I am still looking for the method of multithreading.

Comment: Delphi supports multiple inheritance, but only when using interfaces.  A Delphi class can only have 1 concrete base class, but can implement multiple interfaces.  So you can define an interface to access your members.  Or, you could simply pass them as parameters to the thread class's constructor.

Comment: Thanks Remy. I try the code (just added) but it said TThread is not a type of interface so I cannot add the interface to my form class. Am I missing anything in my code.

Comment: `TThread` is a concrete class not an interface. You cannot inherit `TASKForm` from `TForm` and `TThread`. The point of my earlier suggestion was for you to define a custom `interface` that exposes accessors for your private members, then `TASKForm` can implement those accessors. Then pass `TASKForm`'s interface to the thread so it can access the members when needed.

Comment: But this is overkill if `TASKForm` and the thread are defined in the same unit. The thread will have access to `TASKForm`'s private members (Delphi uses implicit friendship within a unit) so all you really need to do is pass the `TASKForm` object pointer to the thread and then it can access the Form's object's members directly.

Comment: You don't want to do this. You want to move the data out of the form and into the thread class. Having a thread access state in a form is terrible code smell.

Answer (score 1):

## Edited in light of David Heffernan's Comments.

Step 1. Create a Descendant of TThread with a callback procedure - like this

```
type
  TOnMyExecute = procedure( Sender : TObject ) of object; // sender not required here but is convention

  TMyThread = class( TThread )
    private 
      fMyOnExecute : TOnMyExecute;
    public
    procedure Execute(); override; // inside this I need to call TASKForm.MonitorA.somemethod, TASKForm.ConstB.somemethod and TASKForm.calculateStmp
    property MyOnExecute : TMyOnExecute read fMyOnExecute write fMyOnExecute;
  end;
```

Step 2 Create your descendant of TForm pretty much as before.

```
TASKForm = class(TForm)
  protected
    MyThread : TMyThread;
  private
    MonitorA :TMonClassA;
    ConstB :TConstClassB;

    procedure calculateStmp;
    procedure MyPrivateActions( Sender : TObject );
end;
```

Somewhere, probably in TaskForm.Create or when the thread is started assign MyPrivateActions to MyTask.MyOnExecute

```
MyTask.MyOnExecute := MyPrivateActions;
```

Finally the TMyThread OnExecute looks like this

```
TMyThread.OnExecute;
begin
  if assigned( fMyOnExecute ) then
  begin
    fMyOnExecute( self );
  end;
end;
```

The point is that although the thread is executing the function, the function belongs to the form, which can access its own private members.

Comment: TThead was used in the question

Comment: Indeed. Of course, your code uses `TTask`. Which comes from the threading library. Which XE does not have. The threading library was introduced in XE7. And even so `TTask` should not be subclassed. What's more, I don't think it has a virtual `Execute` method. Did you mean `TThread` rather than `TTask`?

Comment: Problem with your thread sub-class is that it must be started suspended. You should remove the `MyOnExecute` property and instead supply that information in a constructor.

Comment: Yes, it must be either be started suspended or the callback given as part of the create procedure. If you are suggesting that MonitorA and ConstB be passed as parameters to the constructor, certainly that is possible, but the TAskForm then loses control of the variables, which kind of defeats the object of private variables to me.

Comment: No. The `TOnMyExecute` should be passed to the thread's constructor. So that you don't compel the consumer to create suspended. At which point the property is pointless and should be removed. Anyway, a far bigger problem is that the asker's entire design and approach is wrong.